# How to prevent MacOS from dropping Git Access

Tags: git, macos, ssh

I have a MacBook Pro with Monterey 12.6. Every time my computer goes to sleep, it drops my Git access credentials. In order to reestablish SSH access, I have to go through the routine of re-adding:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add -l -E sha256
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id\_rsa
```

I can not image the the whole MacOs community is going through this every time their computer sleeps. What is the solution?

thanks.

Comment: I asked this question on the Apple Developer community and no one replied.

Comment: Credentials for what?

Comment: _"it drops my Git access credentials"_ - what does this mean? SSH access to what?

Comment: On macOS, never run `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` in the first place and you won't have this issue. (Note that you *do* want the `eval` on most other systems, although it's possible to set up Linux so that you don't.)

Comment: @CarlNorum  SSH Credentials to gain access into Github

Answer (score 2):

The `ssh` command-line utility included with MacOS includes a feature to store ssh key passphrases in your keychain (a MacOS system for storing sensitive information). As described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2449/_index.html) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/250572/5029), Add the option:

```
    UseKeychain yes
```

to your `.ssh/config` file, and `ssh` will store key passphrases in your keychain.

Note this feature is an Apple-specific addition to the `ssh` command provided with MacOS. If you run a copy of ssh that you obtained from some third party such as Homebrew, it may not have this feature.